# Set of Hermitian matrices is closed

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set $X=\{S\in M_2(\mathbb C):A=A^* \}$

Further given that all the eigen values of $A$ have modulus less than equal to 1.

Is the set $S$ compact?

I know that a Hermitian Matrix is Unitarily Diagonalisable by the Spectral theorem .So every element in $S$ is of the form $$
        \begin{matrix}
        a & 0 \\
        0 & b  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

where $|a|\leq 1;|b|\leq 1$

Hence bounded ;

But I cant show the set is closed ?

Any help

Comment: This doesn't help solve your problem ( answered below ), diagonalisable is not the same as diagonal.

Comment: I think the point "learnmore" is trying to make is that the set of Hermitian matrices is bounded (since each is bounded by $1$) and they want a proof that this set is also closed.  And then their confusion is actually that "closed" plus "bounded" equals compact (which is FALSE ... in this case).

Comment: @learnmore do you understand the statement of Heine-Borel correctly?

Comment: @Squirtle: I'm not sure I understand you.  The Heine-Borel theorem is valid in any finite-dimensional normed space.  Such as, for instance, the space of $2 \times 2$ complex matrices with the Hilbert-Schmidt norm, in which this set is both closed and bounded, and hence is compact.

Comment: Oh... yeah.  I was thinking about the infinite dimensional "matrices" (didn't read the question carefully... sorry about that).

Answer (score 0):

Take a net (or sequence) of Hermitian matrices $A_t \to A$.  It suffices to show that $A$ is Hermitian.  What can you say about $x_t = \langle A_t x,y \rangle - \langle A_t^* x,y \rangle$?

Comment: HINT:  You can say quite a bit!

Comment: What's the limit of a sequence with constant value.....

Comment: I am not getting what you said as" hint"